# create limited instances of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, locationlistener

I am fetching user's location in a service, that implements LocationListener. And in `OnlocationChanged()` method, I am creating an instance of `asynctask` class that will upload the values to an online database. The problem is that, as soon as the `OnlocationChanged()` method is called by Listener, a new instance of `asynctask` is created and it slows down the device. I want a method/mechanism to limit the instances of `asynctask` to *at most* 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite similar to Thread Pools in java ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)).

```
public class MaxAsyncHandler {

 private static MaxAsyncHandler instance = new MaxAsyncHandler();
 ArrayList<Data> list;
 int count;
 int MAX = 5;


 private MaxAsyncHandler() {
  this.count = 0;
  list = new ArrayList<Data>();
 }

 public int getCount() { return count; }

 public int incCount() { count++; }

 public static MaxAsyncHandler getInstance()
 {  
   return instance;
 }

 public void createTask(Data data) {
  if(count < MAX) 
     new AsyncTask(data); // 
  else
     list.add(data);
 }

 // Call this method when an AsyncTask finishes
 public void checkPool() {
  if(list.size() > 0)
    new AsyncTask(list.get(0)); //
 }
}
```

PS : I used a singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

use boolean variable isLoading and initialize it to false.

In AsynctTask  inside onPreExcecute make isLoading true and in onPostExecute make isLoading false

Now before calling asynctask you just need to put following condition and its done. I guess thats what you want

if(!isLoading)
  new LongOperation().execute("");

Answer (score 0):

you could inherit from `AsyncTask` and create your own class, then use static variable to track the instance number.

```
public class MyAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends
    AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

private static int COUNT = 0;
private static int LIMITATION = 5;

public MyAsyncTask() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    COUNT++;
    if (COUNT > LIMITATION) {
        // TODO:
        // FIXME:
        throw new RuntimeException("no more than " + LIMITATION
                + " asyn task");
    }
}

public static void resetCounter() {
    COUNT = 0;
}

@Override
protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(java.lang.Object[])
 */
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

}
```